# Dynamic Content Loading and Interaction with Splash in Scrapy: Email Input Popup Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm working on a Scrapy spider that involves interacting with a webpage using Splash. The webpage has a dynamic email login feature where, upon clicking the "E-posta adresiyle devam et" (Continue with email) button, an email input field appears for the user to enter their email.

I'm facing an issue where the Splash script doesn't seem to find the email input field, possibly because it's dynamically loaded after the button click, and the URL doesn't change. The email input field is not in a separate window but rather a dynamic part of the main page.

Here's a simplified version of my Lua script:

```
-- ... (previous script code)

-- Click the "E-posta adresiyle devam et" (Continue with email) button
local email_login_button = splash:select('button[data-aut-id="emailLogin"]')
email_login_button:click()

-- Wait for the email input field to appear
assert(splash:wait_for_selector('input[name=email]'))

-- Fill in the email field
local email_input = splash:select('input[name=email]')
email_input:send_text("byemin00@gmail.com")
assert(splash:wait(1))

-- ... (rest of the script)
```

and here's my main Scrapy spider code along with the Lua script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Response
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import base64

lua_script = """
-- ... (your Lua script)
"""

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'login_letgo'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.letgo.com/#loginemail'
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, endpoint="execute", args={'wait': 1, 
                                                   'lua_source': lua_script,
                                                   "ua" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36",
                                                   'width': 1000
                                                   })

    def parse(self, response):
        # ... (your existing parse method)
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.content)
        filename = 'after_login.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
        # ... (rest of your parse method)
```

In my Scrapy spider, I have implemented a Splash script to interact with a webpage that has a dynamic email login feature. Here are the key steps I have taken:

1. I use `splash:wait` to ensure the page is fully loaded before interacting with elements.
2. I identify the "E-posta adresiyle devam et" (Continue with email) button and clicked it.
3. I use `splash:wait_for_selector` to wait for the appearance of the email input field.

However, despite these efforts, it seems that the Splash script is not capturing the appearance of the email input field. The issue may be related to the dynamic nature of the content loading. Even though the URL doesn't change upon clicking the button, the email input field appears as part of the main page, not in a separate window.

I'm seeking guidance on how to effectively handle dynamic content loading and interaction in Splash when the URL doesn't change. Specifically, how can I ensure that the Splash script correctly identifies and interacts with dynamically loaded elements?

Comment: I got this error in the last code: `[scrapy_splash.middleware] WARNING: Bad request to Splash: {'error': 400, 'type': 'ScriptError', 'description': 'Error happened while executing Lua script', 'info': {'source': '[string "..."]', 'line_number': 12, 'error': "attempt to call method 'wait_for_selector' (a nil value)", 'type': 'LUA_ERROR', 'message': 'Lua error: [string "..."]:12: attempt to call method \'wait_for_selector\' (a nil value)'}}`